# Volumetric object where the volume gets less dense towards the edges?

Tags: volumetrics

I have 2 spheres. 1, the outer one isn't selected while sphere 2 (the inner one) is selected.
I want to make sphere 1 a volumetric object surrounding sphere 2 where the volume gets less dense towards the outer part of the sphere. How do I do this?
[image]

Comment: anisotropy in the volume scatter shader is what controls this. Usually it's most noticable in the viewing angle, but maybe could be used that way too.